# Javascript- global varaible value not being properly reflected outside code block

Tags: javascript, promise, global-variables

I have set global variable (boolean) to be false, then inside code block I set it to true and I export this varaiable to write unit test.

I am sure I have hit the code still I see the value to be false!!!

here is  the code snippet

```
var bWrittenRegistry = false;

function setOrUnsetRegistry(regValue){
 let promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve((async () => {

      if(somecondition){

       regedit.putValue({
        'HKLM\\System\\CurrentControlSet': {
          'something': {
            value: regValue,
            type: 'REG_SZ'
           }
        }
      },function(err) {//callback
          console.log("called");//printed
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error22" + err);
          }else {
               bWrittenRegistry = true;
               console.log(bWrittenRegistry);// prints true
           }
       }
     );
   }

  }))();
 }

Inside test.spec.js

 it('should set or unset unset variable in registry',function(done){
        this.timeout(300000);
        somefunc.setOrUnsetRegistry(1).then(function(){
        console.log(somefunc.bWrittenRegistry);//prints false
        expect(somefunc.bWrittenRegistry).to.equal(true);//test fails
        done();
        })

  })
```

I believe something asynchronous is happening, but I want in the it must print 'true' after callback

Comment: use `var` instead of `let` if you need to scope that variable in that way. Let is more tightly scoped.

Comment: @Gavin—it's declared as a global, that's not very "tight". ;-)

Comment: you are not simulating the error case in your test from what I can see, also you have an async but no await in your code... you should be resolving after your condition is met or rejecting if error occurs... but you are resolving immediately..

Comment: I have changed code instead 'let' I declared global variable to be 'var' still issue persist, when I expect variable to be true, test fails